# static methods inheritance in backbone over different modules

Tags: class, inheritance, backbone.js, coffeescript, static-methods

I am using backbone.js for a web app.

I have different component views which are derived from few base classes.
Each of the view has few static methods for initializing and creating instances.

For example:

```
class Base extends Backbone.View
  @create:(config)->
      *do some processing based on config*
      *generate view parameters*
      viewparams = ....
      return new @(viewparams)
class Derived extends Base
  **some customizations and functions**

**at some point some where**
instanceDerived = Derived.create(*some params*)
```

The advantage of this method is that, it becomes natural to re-use the create method. The "@" or "this" refers to the Derived class (constructor) and hence the object can be created easily.

The code works well when both the classes are in same module. However, when the objects are in different modules, the "@" or "this" inside create function refers to "Base.create" instead of the Derived class constructor.

I dont know if I am doing some unconventional coding here. Can some one please advice of how to resolve/structure this problem?

Comment: @ in create refers to Derived class (see: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/9cvVv/3/ ) . Can you setup an example on jsfiddle where it's referring it to Base ?

Comment: What do you mean in another "module"? What kind of module?

Comment: the module is another JavaScript file loaded by require.js